# Sitecore Trivia - Anyone know the story behind admin / b username/password?

Tags: security

Who originally picked admin / b username and password combo? Is there a story a behind it? Why b?

I'm just curious if there is a story behind it.

Comment: b was introduced somewhere in Sitecore6.. in v5 it was empty. No idea why "b" though

Comment: I guess b is chosen because b comes after "a" from admin in alphabetic order.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It was I that changed the default password to 'b', but it wasn't the result of a great meaningful insight, clever security considerations or a joke.

Truth is I was implementing the Change Password dialog and was flipping between 'a' and 'b'. The dialog happened to work when I was on 'b', and the 'b' password remained in the product.

I think this was in CMS v5+ - not v5.0 because the dialog was added later as far as I remember.

Answer (score 5):

Word on the street is it was a matter of preference.

[image]

Comment: A would be too easy to guess and surely the invasor would not try b 